# How to backup realm db to iCloud with Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to implement a function to backup realm db to iCloud
https://medium.com/swlh/backup-your-applications-data-with-icloud-and-track-progress-48a00ebd2891

I finished the setting by referring to the site above.
And I entered the code according to the method of the site, but with no success.

So I tried again like below.
Still I can't see the file in the app in settings.
Is there something wrong?

And I am curious about how to restore to realm db in iCloud.
Thank you

```
func uploadDatabaseToCloudDrive()
{

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    //let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents", isDirectory: true)

    let iCloudDocumentToCheckURL = iCloudDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
    let realmArchiveURL = iCloudDocumentToCheckURL

    if(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: iCloudDocumentsURL.path ))
    {
        do
        {
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: realmArchiveURL)
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.writeCopy(toFile: realmArchiveURL)

        }catch
        {
            print("ERR")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Need to store ")
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.writeCopy(toFile: realmArchiveURL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting questions, it's a good idea to ensure the question is understandable include complete code so we can duplicate the issue. First, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, saying *Still I can't see the file in the app in settings* has no meaning to us. App settings? What settings? What are you expecting to see? Lastly, there's a bunch of set up steps needed before writing a file to iCloud; provisioning, signing. Also, you're not following that article as it's using fileManager to do the write.

Comment: Oh and on `.writeCopy` don't forge that [The destination file cannot already exist](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V9writeCopy6toFile13encryptionKeyy10Foundation3URLV_AG4DataVSgtKF)